# Upload Progress in IE7

Tags: php, javascript, html

does anybody of you know a way to show the Upload Progress in Internet Explorer?
I am currently using an Ajax uploader and i just need a simple Upload Progress Display.
(The upload itself works in IE, but i need an Progress... a Percent would be just great..)

Any Idea?

Comment: what have you tried?If you show us the code and say where you got struck and we can suggest you.

Comment: Currently, i didnt tried much. I just need a working Upload Progress Display for IE7 - IE9... I don't think you need to see code? But if so, say me which part(s)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot do this in old IE browsers without using server-side hacks and additional requests to update the status or e.g. a flash/java-based uploader.

Comment: What about flash? Can i use it without changing my current Code that much? It just have to send the File and some Form-Contents...

Comment: Have a look at http://www.plupload.com/ - it automatically chooses a suitable upload backend. Minor modifications to your code are most likely necessary.

Comment: Flash is baaad baaad today. I'd stay away from that solution unless this is very important for you. The internet will in a few years be without Flash. Worth keeping in mind.

Comment: Still better than using Java. Besides that, it would only be used in old browsers not supporting XHR FormData.

Comment: The Problem is i need to do that for work and if the only solution is Flash i have to chose Flash. No other ways. :(